# blockchain getjson javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, getjson, bitcoin

I'm trying to get a bitcoin address info using the Blockchain.info API but it doesn't work. I get allways the same error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blockchain.info/address/13DKdDeZcdLbGoNquWz8nHBnVpfBVkDitz?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:57366' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My code is:

```
$.getJSON("https://blockchain.info/address/13DKdDeZcdLbGoNquWz8nHBnVpfBVkDitz?format=json",
function(data) {$('#blockchain').append(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

I've tryed the same code with another API and it works:

```
$.getJSON("http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/txs/13DKdDeZcdLbGoNquWz8nHBnVpfBVkDitz",
function(data) {$('#blockr').append(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

The problem is that I need some information that is only available by the blockchain API.

Any idea?

Comment: This still doesn't work. Docs say you can add &cors=true but that has zero impact.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `dataType: 'jsonp'` instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://blockchain.info/address/13DKdDeZcdLbGoNquWz8nHBnVpfBVkDitz?format=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#blockchain').append(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Felix for you answer. If I use your code I get a: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 13DKdDeZcdLbGoNquWz8nHBnVpfBVkDitz:2'. I think it has something to do with dataType: jsonp. Maybe Blockchain is returning a JSON format and I am calling for a JSONP. I don't know.